# Pandas way to check if an event has already happend python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that we have a Pandas DataFrame (df) as:

| nickname | event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2020-01-02 |
| A | 1 | 2020-01-03 |
| B | 0 | 2020-01-02 |
| B | 0 | 2020-01-03 |
| C | 1 | 2020-01-02 |
| C | 1 | 2020-01-03 |

Is there a quick and elegant way of getting only the lines where the nickname has never had an 1 event? Like

| nickname | event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 0 | 2020-01-02 |
| B | 0 | 2020-01-03 |

I came up with the following code to solve this problem

```py
df_group= df.groupby('nickname')['event'].max()
df_never = df_group[df_group == 0]
df_only_never = df[df['nickname'].isin(df_never .index)]
```

I have the feeling that there is a one-line way of doing this with Pandas, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes are close.  Instead of using `.max()` which aggregate and reduce the number of rows, you can use [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) on `'max'` to make all group values equal to the maximum value (either 0 or 1 for whole group).

Then, like you did, check these values for equality with `0` to get a boolean index.

Finally, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) on the boolean index to locate the rows of group(s) with all zeros, as follows:

```
df_out = df.loc[df.groupby('nickname')['event'].transform('max') == 0]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  nickname  event        Date
2        B      0  2020-01-02
3        B      0  2020-01-03
```

Comment: @EduardoPacheco  You are welcome!  Make good use of the `.transform()` function which gives you the same number of original rows.  Hence, you can then use the result together with your column for direct comparison and other operations not possible when you get the aggregated results by `.agg()` with less rows.   Happy programming!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.groupby` + `.filter`:

```py
x = df.groupby("nickname").filter(lambda x: x["event"].eq(0).all())
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  nickname  event        Date
2        B      0  2020-01-02
3        B      0  2020-01-03
```